# Discount vs. off

Tags: idioms

I wonder if someone could tell me which one of the following sentences sounds idiomatic:

> a) These jeans have 25% off.
>   b) These jeans have 25% discount.
>   c) These jeans have a discount of 25%.
>   d) These jeans are selling for 25% off.
>   e) These jeans are selling at a discount of 25%.

For me only `d` and `e` are idiomatic and both seem to be natural and of course identical.

Comment: You missed out **b1** - *These jeans have **a** 25% discount* (and many other permutations & slight variations) They're all fine, but **e** is a bit "wordy", and wouldn't often occur in natural speech.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> These jeans are 25 percent off.

is even more idiomatic.  There's nothing wrong with d) or e).  A small change to b) or c) gives:

> These jeans have a 25% discount.

which is a little more natural than d) or e).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply Oldcat, but what would be the most idiomatic way of telling the same thing as you offered just using the word "discount"?

Comment: "These jeans are at a discount" or "these jeans are discounted". If you want the percent, then you add 25% before the word discount in the first case and after it in the second.